# Лупа при наведении на картинку (css,hover)

Tags: jquery, javascript, html5, css

Всем привет! Интересует вопрос, как сделать так, чтобы при наведении на картинку (hover) иконка мышки превращалась в лупу?
Под лупой я не имею ввиду плагин Jquery Zoomer, мне просто нужно заменить cursor при hover'е на картинку.

Comment: "иконка мышки", а точнее курсор, не превращается, а под так называемой "лупой", используется элемент, например div.

P.S. Для лучшего понимания, [набросал вам примерчик][1]. Хотя, может я не правильно понял, о каком плагине вы говорите и вам действительно надо только изменить вид курсора, тогда ответ @dekameron - правильное направление.

   [1]:http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/gQav5/

Comment: Это потрясающе, ещё только: cursor: none; для лупы.

Comment: @Deonis ух ты, круто! Только вот @dekameron понял о чем речь, видимо я неясно выразился. Чтож, все равно спасибо :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#div:hover{cursor: url("http://i.webkub.com/loupa.cur");}
```

Конвертировать свою картинку в формат .cur можно [Здесь](http://www.digitalcoding.com/tools/image-converter.html)